# As imagens salvas no BD e na pasta raiz do projeto nao aparecem no site

Tags: php, sql, netbeans

Estou progrmando em um site , usando a linguagem php no netBeans e easyphp p banco. o site cadastra empresas e servicos e tambem e possivel pesquisar por nome as mesmas.(esta em processo de desenvolvimento)

clicando na imagem a parece o erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'codigo_EMPRESA']?>'' at line 1

linhas de código:

classe busca empresa e index:

classe Busca Empresa:

```
<?php
require_once "EmpresasDAO.php";
$objBDEmpresas = new EmpresasDAO();
// busca por nome
if (isset($_GET['HTML_nome_EMPRESA'])) {

    $busca = $_GET['HTML_nome_EMPRESA'];
    $rsEmpresas = $objBDEmpresas->listaEmpresas(2, $busca);
}
// busca por regiao
if (isset($_GET['reg'])) {

    $codReg = $_GET['reg'];
    $rsEmpresas = $objBDEmpresas->listaEmpresas(3, $codReg);
}
?>
<table align="center" width="60%">
    <tr>
        <?php
        //enquanto houver empresas no rsEmpresas
        while ($tblEmpresas = mysql_fetch_array($rsEmpresas)) {
            ?>       
            <td align="center">
                <a href="index.php?codPg=110&codEmp=<?= $tblEmpresas['codigo_EMPRESA'] ?>">
                    <img src="_images/_system/<?= $tblEmpresas['logo_EMPRESA'] ?>" width="150" height="100"><br>
                    <?= $tblEmpresas['nome_EMPRESA'] ?>
                </a>
            </td>            
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    </div>

    <div id="DivMenu">
        <?php
            include "MenuHome.php";                
        ?>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <div id="DivConteudo">
        <?php
            //mapeamento de links

            if(!isset($_GET['codPg']) || $_GET['codPg'] == 0){
                include "ListaEmpresas.php";
                //include "ListaServicos.php;
                //include "ListaParceiros.php;
            }else{
                 if($_GET['codPg'] == 100)
                    include "BuscaEmpresa.php";
                if($_GET['codPg'] == 110)
                    include "PerfilEmpresa.php";                   
                if($_GET['codPg'] == 120)
                    include "FormEmpresas.php";                   
                if($_GET['codPg'] == 130)
                    include "FormServicos.php";                   

            }
        ?>

    </div>     

</body>
```

Gostaria de entender o motivo das imagens não aparecerem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode mostrar o `SQL` e a estrutura do banco de dados ?

Comment: Aperta o F12 no seu navegador e vá até a aba de network, possivelmente a URL da imagem esteja errada, se for o caso, irá aparecer em vermelho na listagem dos arquivos.

Comment: @Augusto Atualizei o post com as imagens.

Comment: @JeffersonSalvador Sim aparece em vermelho(conforme print no post) e da o erro 404 not found ,mas estranho porque o camiho da imagem é: C:\phpcic\Empresas_images_system    *esse tambem e o caminhodo Alias e o nome e phpcic (eu uso o easyphp)

Comment: @WesleySouza, se observar no erro em vermelho vai ver que tem fragmentos de PHP, isso deveria estar convertido já. Tente substituir o "<?=" por "<?php echo" no seu código, penso que o "short_open_tag" não esteja ativo na sua instalação

Comment: @JeffersonSalvador, eu ja tinha alterado o short para:                           ; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On                                                                                             mas realizando a alteração(inclusive estou fazendo isso em outras classes tambem) que você propõs as imagens apareceram , Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Manda um print do código fonte do depois de exibido no browser

Comment: @JeffersonSalvador Feito!

Comment: É o código fonte gerado pelo navegador, depois de processar o PHP @WesleySouza

Comment: @JeffersonSalvador  Esse?

Comment: Isso mesmo @WesleySouza. Se você pegar a url da imagem e colar na barra de endereços do browser a imagem aparece?

Comment: Sim @JeffersonSalvador Perfeitamente !, agora vou colocar validações nos campos de cadastro , melhorar o layout ,Muito obrigado novamente

Comment: O erro ainda é o inicial que você postou ou agora simplesmente as imagens não aparecem?

Comment: Apos a sua dica da substituição do <?= por <?php echo , todas as imagens apareceram normamelmente!